# MySQL query returns most matches first

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a query which should return array or titles of most matches by keywords searched. Not sure if even the query is as it should be, but it works. And don't worry about injections, I'll work on that later. Target here is to return title of row which has most results.

```
   $query = "SELECT * ";
   $query .= "FROM user_rec ";
   $query .= "WHERE sast1 = '" . $mekletie[0] . "'";
   $query .= "OR sast1 = '" . $mekletie[1] . "'";
   $query .= "OR sast1 = '" . $mekletie[2] . "'";

/*NOTE - the query isn't complete yet, it will run sast2 next and so on until sast5 
 and compare all the same searched keywords */

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    if (!$result) {
       die ("DB query nedarbojas");
    }
```

Comment: It is not clear what is the problem or what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want to do this:

```
$query = 
"SELECT * 
FROM
  (SELECT
    u.*,
    ( sast1 = '" . $mekletie[0] . "' +
      sast1 = '" . $mekletie[1] . "' +
      sast1 = '" . $mekletie[2] . "' +
      sast2 = '" . $mekletie[0] . "' +
      sast2 = '" . $mekletie[1] . "' +
      sast2 = '" . $mekletie[2] . "' ) AS numberofmatches
  FROM user_rec ) m
WHERE
  m.numberofmatches > 0
ORDER BY
  m.numberofmatches DESC";
```

But it won't work, because if `sast1` matches `$mekletie[0]` then it won't match `$mekletie[1]`, unless they are the same, but then it's not very useful in the first place.

[edit]
I see your comment, stating that there is a stat2 as well. In that case, you can use this approach. But if you are storing keywords for a user, you might want to consider a separate table with keywords, which you can join like this:

```
$query = 
"SELECT
  u.*
FROM
  user_rec u
  -- Inner join implicitly excludes users that don't have any matching tag.
  INNER JOIN user_tag t ON t.userid = u.userid
WHERE
  t.tag IN ('" .$mekletie[0] . "', '" . $mekletie[1] . "', '" . $mekletie[2] . "')
GROUP BY
  -- Mysql, unlike other databases, allows you to specify only the id 
  -- in group by when actually returning other fields as well.
  u.userid
ORDER BY
  -- You can return the count, or use it just for sorting.
  COUNT(t.userid) DESC"
```

Comment: If any of the $mekletie matches sast1 we jump to sast 2 and continue the query